# Increase amount with value of each matching record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables

```
TableA:
ID  Amount
1   100

TableB:
ID  Interest
1   10
1   20
```

I want to increase the TableA.Amount by each mating record's interest in TableB. How to write an update statement for this? I have tried below, but it updates Amount with only first matching record.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Amount = a.Amount + b.Intereset
FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

This is the result I got:

```
TableA:
ID  Amount
1   110
```

However, the expected result is:

```
TableA:
ID  Amount
1   130
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

`Correlated sub-query`

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Amount = Amount + ISNULL((SELECT sum(b.Intereset) 
                              FROM TableB b                
                              WHERE TableA.ID = b.ID),0)
```

or Use `Cross Apply`

```
UPDATE a 
SET    amount = amount + total_interest 
FROM   tablea a 
       CROSS apply (SELECT Sum(b.intereset) 
                    FROM   tableb b 
                    WHERE  a.id = b.id) cs (total_interest)
```

Comment: This is a good answer... though i'd be sure to handle NULL values appropriately or you'll end up with NULL amounts in TableA if none exist in TableB

Comment: If you just wrap the values being added (the select statement in the first example and `total_interest` in the second example) with `ISNULL`, then it would be all set.

Comment: @gmm - we don't need for `isnull` for `cross apply` version since it will bring only matched records.

Comment: Thanks @vr46! The first query itself is useful for me. Just one more related question I have. If I want to update two columns in TableA, then will it work well with single query too? I mean for example, to increase Amount by Interest and say.. also increase Bonus with BonusInterest? Assuming these additional columns in both tables respectively?

Comment: @AnilSoman - yes, But if you use first query then one more time you need to use `sub-query`. Better use Cross Apply method

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about non-matching values, then the best solution is to use a `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE a
    SET Amount = a.Amount + b.SumInterest
    FROM TableA a JOIN
         (SELECT SUM(b.interest) as SumInterest
          FROM TableB b
          GROUP BY b.id
         ) b
         ON a.id = b.id;
```